# ASP.NET Authentication cookies (Web Farm)

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, web-farm, formsauthentication

I use FormsAuthentication

I have a web farm with 2 nodes. What I do :

1) I log-in to my site by means of my factory through 1st node and go to default page.

2) I switch off 1st node, so next request should be to my 2nd node.

3) I'm trying to request some page(which should be available if I'm logged in) but application redirects me to login url. I think because of incorrect or missing cookies.

I used machine key
something like :

```
<machineKey
     validationKey="C50B3C89CB21F4F1422FF158A5B42D0E8DB8CB5CDA1742572A487D9401E3400267682B202B746511891C1BAF47F8D25C07F6C39A104696DB51F17C529AD3CABE" 
      decryptionKey="8A9BE8FD67AF6979E7D20198CFEA50DD3D3799C77AF2B72F" 
      validation="SHA1" />
```

But It still do not work.
I am doing almost the same as described here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx

But it just do not work for me.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Since I use ms sql to store session my ASP.NET_SessionId cookies are the same from one request to another but if I logged on 1st node and get .ASPXFORMSAUTH cookie to set. And after I go to another node with this cookie - this node do not understand this cookie and redirect me to login page.

Comment: In your system.web section of your web.config file, you have a sessionState element with mode="SQLServer" or mode="StateServer"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in security updates.
As soon as we installed updates the problem was solved.

Here is the list of possible updates which impact on this:

```
Security Update KB2656351
Security Update KB2487376
Security Update KB2633870
Security Update KB2572078
Security Update KB2518870
```